# Java Spring MVC + Hibernate Class Composition

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, orm

I am starting a project with Spring MVC and Hibernate. I am concerned about best practices related to class composition. Suppose I had a class called User with an ORM technology like Hibernate.

I am not sure if I should include **everything** related to the User entity inside of the User class. I know that Hibernate automatically improves performance by lazy loading so it does not retrieve all instance variables when we retrieve a user. However, I feel like if we included too much variables in the User class, it will become very expensive to query User objects.

Consider this example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User{

private String username;
private String password;
private long user_id;

private Collection<Transaction> transactions;

}
```

Here the User class stores a collection of transactions. Each transaction represents a purchase that user made on the website. But we do not need to store a transactions collection for every user.

Instead, we can make a transaction table like so:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "UserTransactions)
 public class Transaction{

    private int user_id;
    private int order_id;
    private double amount_paid;
}
```

With this transaction table, we can still store every transaction every user has made.

This is only an example, there are many more variables that do not need to be stored in the User class and can be represented by their own table. So I am wondering if there is any harm to storing all of these variables in the User class, or should we be careful and be selective of what we include in the User class? What would be the pros/cons of each approach?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to ask? How to create relationships between hibernate entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a one-to-many relationship between User and UserTransation. A User can have many transactions and a transaction is made by one and only one user.

So I don't understand why you are wondering if you should store everything in User. You cannot. You have to have 2 domain objects User and UserTransaction with a one-to-many relationship (with a User and a (User)Transaction table in the database). Then, when you query a User with Hibernate, by default use "lazy-loading" to not make a join with Transaction. For data access patterns that needs Transaction, explicity make a "fetch join" to get the User and its transactions in a single SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to store all the variables in database then you can restrict them using

```
 @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false) or @transient
```

and using transaction table will be a more better approach where only transaction_id and user_id are there and rest all the user details you can store in some other table as it will be more organized and normalized and will cause less overhead